# What's the main difference of either and neither?

Tags: grammar, either-any, neither

One of my friends told me about the "either" usage:

> Let's say you hate food A, and you hate food B. You go to a restaurant
> and are asked, "Would you like A or B?" The natural response would be,
> "I don't want either." –  WhatRoughBeast

If definition of "either" is:
" You have to choose one, but you don't like both offered choice. "

Then what about neither?

When do we use "neither" and what does it mean?

Comment: Either - one or the other of two, neither - not one or the other of two. Do you want to eat coal or broken glass? You can say _I don't want either_ or _I want neither_.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. Etymologically speaking, ***n**either* = ***not** either*

Comment: How does either of your comments differ from my answer, really??

Comment: @Lambie - well, your answer wasn't there when I wrote my comment above. I do apologise however, and will definitely make sure to clear any comments with you in future. I am sure that Fumblefingers is as equally abjectly sorry.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey and (so far) 8 other people missed the joke...

Comment: 'Neither' is a one-word stand alone replacement for "I don't want either" in a conversation.

Comment: @evildemonic - do explain the alleged 'joke'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I thought it was funny. I'm not in the business of explaining humor to people. This is the best I can do...Hint: "either"

Comment: @evildemonic - at the risk of being frowned on for excessive use of metaphor, I will say that I might fail to understand a 'joke' either because it flies over my head, or under my radar. After careful examination of the above, I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your definition of "either" is incorrect. It means more like "one or the other".

"Neither" is "not" + "either", so it means something like "not the one and not the other".

So in your context, "I don't want either" means "I don't want A and I don't want B", which is exactly the intent.

We almost never say "not either" together. Instead, we say "neither". So in your context, we cannot say "I want *not either*", so the natural response with "neither" is:

> I want neither.

Comment: But in UK "Estuary English" at least, you'll commonly hear "double negative" forms like *He don't want niver* and *She don't want nuffink*.

Comment: Neither is common in many dialects in place of either, but if you're learning English it makes sense to learn the proper rule first.

Comment: It's funny but I think my answer is much clearer than yours. Sorry.

Comment: @Lambie Indeed, but who are we against so many?

Comment: @gotube - _vox populi, vox dei_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey From your fingertips to God's screen.

Answer (score 2):

I want neither (one). = I don't want either (one).

They mean: I want neither food A nor food B.
I do not want either food A or food B.

**Mnemonic trick**:
Think of verbs: I **don't eat** pastry. I eat *no* pastry. Two ways to say the same thing.

However, bear in mind that with the neither or no versions, you might sound slightly stilted. :)

Comment: It's an application of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) outside of the context where they are usually used. not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B). 
The former is "I don't want either". The latter is "I want neither".

Comment: @Opifex I have explained how to use it and my examples are exactly like yours. That said, this is not a logic course.

Comment: relax buddy... I was just providing some extra trivia, which could be useful if OP has some knowledge of boolean algebra. When I read your answer, it made me philosophize about how it works, and it struck me how clear the parallel was with De Morgan's laws, even though they are generally used in an entirely different context. No need to get upset.